# How do I fix the floating glitch that is happening to my Player Ball?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-science

I am using Unity3D to make a replica of the game "Rolling Sky" which you can find on the Google/Apple app store. I was able to make a simple floor which the ball will move on and I was also able to make the ball (Player) move left and right. After moving the ball a couple of times back and fourth, it starts float in the air and eventually what it seems like is change it's axis.

I came up with a couple of alternatives that I think would work, but I had trouble coming up with the code to make it function properly.

1) Do not rotate the ball at all. Just have it smoothly move back and forth.
^^ Probably the best solution I could come up with.

or

2) Use CharacterController to have complete control of how the ball reacts to different events, scenarios, etc.
^^ This would probably be the most necessary and hardest of I had to guess.

or

3) Move the ball an x amount of pixels everytime I move left or right.
^^ I would assume this would create a lot more glitches than what I have right now.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I was able to provide my own answer, but if anyone has any alternatives, feel free to post your solution!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the player ball from floating into the sky, no other code was needed. Simply go to the Rigidbody component on the Player and expand the "Constraints" menu. Next, check the axis boxes that you would like to freeze the rotation on to prevent the ball from spinning like so in the picture.

Click the link to see the picture
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7XpS.png).

In this case, I did not freeze the ball on the x axis because I eventually want to animate it to spin as if it is rolling forward.

Answer (score 0):

### You're using `transform.Translate`

and

### You're using `Vector3.right`

---

`transform.Translate` will directly move the ball without thought of rotation. You will need to take the object's rotation into consideration when translating. You can also use the physics engine and use `Rigidbody.MovePosition` to force position or `Rigidbody.AddForce` to utilize physics interactions.

`Vector3.right` will use the constant value equivalent to Vector3(1, 0, 0). This will not be in regard to the object's rotation or facing.

I suggest looking through [Unity's tutorial for a ball-roller](https://learn.unity.com/project/roll-a-ball-tutorial) and see how they complete the task of user input with a user controlled ball.

Comment: I have watched and participated in their "Roll-A-Ball" tutorial, however, everytime you would release a key to move the ball, the ball would continue to roll. I want the ball to stop right after the the key is lifted and the code that I have used seems to do just that. I do want to work on your suggestion though when it comes to the Rigidbody.MovePosition/AddForce

Comment: That kind of input/output behavior can be changed in the controller logic. Test for `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") <= someDeadZoneFloatValue`. If you're using `Rigidbody`, you could set the velocity and angularvelocity to zero.